# Pickling a file

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, statsmodels, kedro

I using kedro in conjunction with databricks-connect to run my machine learning model. I am trained and tested the model using databricks notebook and saved the pickle file of the model to azure blob storage. To test the pipeline locally I downloaded the pickle file and stored it locally. kedro reads in the file fine when stored locally, however the problem is when I try to read in the file into kedro directly from azure; I get the following error : "Invalid Load Key '?'

Unfortunately I cannot post any screenshots since I am doing this for my job. My thinking is that the pickle file is stored differently while on azure and when downloaded locally it is stored correctly.

For a bit more clarity I am attempting to store a logistic Regression model trained used statsmodels (sm.logit)

Comment: You need to include at least a complete error message and traceback, a single line is too vague.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pickles unfortunately aren't guaranteed to work across environments, at the very least the python version (and possibly OS) need to be identical. Is there a mismatch here?

Comment: It should be; I configured the Kedro environment to use the same version of python being used in databricks